# Determine True or False, justify your statement with a proof or counterexample

Tags: probability

*Question*: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, then $A^c$ and $B$ are independent.

Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, we could say that $P(A∪B) = P(A) +P(B)$, and if $A^c$ and $B$ are independent, we could say that $P(A^c\mid B)=P(B)$, however, I wasn't sure what is next?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the website! If you are satisfied with any of the answers to this and your previous questions, consider accepting them by clicking the tick-mark button next to them. Doing so will provide reputation points to both you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you. If you still have a query, ping the answerers in the comments and try to get a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true unless $A$ or $B$ is an impossible event.

Recall that to prove independence of $A^C,B$ we would need to show $P(A^C\cap B)=P(A^C)P(B)$. Since $A,B$ are disjoint, $B\subseteq A^C$ so that $P(A^C\cap B)=P(B)$. This will equal the RHS $P(B)P(A^C)$ iff $P(A^C)=1$ or $P(B)=0$ i.e. $A$ or $B$ is an impossible event.